# Change focus of fields with ref

Tags: reactjs, ref

I am trying to change focus on button click, but nothing happens. I worked from official react documentation.. My snippet code is:

I defined ref in constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.firstInput = React.createRef()
 }
```

Then write a function to set focus

```
    changeFocus = () => {
       this.firstInput.current.focus()
    }
```

Then defined a button to call function on click

```
  <Button onClick={this.changeFocus}>
    Focus
  </Button>
```

And finaly set ref in component

```
<Col className="pr-md-1" md="3">
  <FormGroup>
    <label>Broj računa</label>
    <Input style={{'borderColor':'lightgray', 'fontSize':'14px'}}
           ref={this.firstInput}
           placeholder="Br.računa"
           type="text"
           value={this.state.accountNumber || (header === null ? "" : header.account_number) }
           onChange={this.changeAccountNumber}
    />
   </FormGroup>
  </Col>
```

Comment: Show `Input` implementation, you need it to pass the ref to the html element.

Comment: Most likely you are not forwarding the ref to the `Input` component. As @DennisVash mentioned, you really need to show us the implementation of the `Input` component...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `reactstrap` (which needs `innerRef` instead of `ref`) so you need the following changes

```
innerRef={(input) => { this.firstInput = input }}
```

and

```
   changeFocus = () => {
       this.firstInput.focus()
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: YES!!! tnx, this is exactly what i need. I am using reactstrap and problem was in ref, I need to use innerRef. tnx a lot